# jQuery prop() does not set checkbox to true

Tags: jquery

the following jQuery 3.2.1 line:
`$("#company-checkbox").attr('disabled', true).prop("checked", true);`

intends to set a checkbox to true and lock it. Indeed visually this happens but in practice when form data are submitted, the checkbox is not submitted with true value. Is this due to `attr('disabled', true)`? How can I have the desired result?

Comment: Use `readonly`, not `disabled`. Disabled inputs aren't submitted.

Comment: You may need to swap prop and attr. In this way, it sets the property first, to checked, and then disabled it. I don't think you can set the property when it's disabled.

Comment: This is working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/fmtgboac/. Can you please update the question with the entire code used?

Comment: As mentioned, visually it works. However checkbox value is not submitted, I finally manipulated it at the server-side (this would be the safest approach). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set), disabled controls are not considered when preparing POST or query string data. If you absolutely have to send something, you can use jQuery to append a hidden input that has same name and value as the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

$(elem).prop("checked") -> true (Boolean) Will change with checkbox state

$(elem).attr("checked")(1.6+) -> "checked" (String) Initial state of the checkbox; does not change

Try using the '**prop**' function only

```
$("#company-checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Answer (score -2):

Please check the input company-checkbox has the attribute "name" set.